# Not able to update data in database in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {            
    $data = array(
        'password' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('npassword'),
    );

    $db->update('eo_user_details',$data,"userid='".$eo_sess->uid."'");
```

I am not able to update data in my database in Zend framework. The above code is what I'm using. I am able to display `$data`, but when I use the `$db->update` statement, `$data` is not getting updated. I am getting session value, the table is correct, is there any problem with my code?

Comment: `var_dump($data)` also, are you sure `$eo_sess->uid` is a string?

Comment: Does a row with such userid exist?

Comment: What is $db here a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract object? If it is, you should not need 3 parameters, first one is data to update and second one is where clause

Comment: $db->update('eo_user_details',$data,"userid='".$eo_sess->uid."'");  eo_user_details is the table name,$data it contains data which is going to update, "userid='".$eo_sess->uid." this is the condition...what should i do? update is not working..

Comment: $eo_sess->uid its the session value..this is also coming..Does a row with such userid exist?  the row exists

Comment: try the update query with a static value, like `$db->update('eo_user_details',$data,"userid='1'");`. see if the row is been updated